# How to show labels for ns2 nodes in nam animation and naming

Tags: network-programming, simulation, ns2

I am trying to build a topology in ns2 and it helps me if in the nam animation the nodes have names so I can understand easier if they are core switches or aggragation or ToR...

I am using a loop to create them and set a label using the label attribute. My code is something like the following

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 4} {incr i} {
    set c($i) [$ns node]
    $c($i) color red
    $c($i) shape hexagon
    $c($i) label "corei" 
    $c($i) label-color black
    $c($i) label-at up
}


$ns duplex-link $c(1) $c(2) 1Gb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $c(3) $c(2) 1Gb 10ms DropTail
```

but when I am running it the nam only shows the hexagons with the number inside them which I assume is an internal counting.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Incidentally would the line

```
$c($i) label "corei"
```

work if it was

```
$c($i) label "core$i"
```

it doesn't produce any errors but like I said no labels

Other than that I was trying to use a naming format like pod_layer_pos for my nodes and I read the post at [Tcl can't read variable: no such variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407983/tcl-cant-read-variable-no-such-variable) but I was wondering if when using arrays - associative - can I have more then one variable evaluated inside the parenthesis. For example can I have the following

```
$ns duplex-link $core($i) $pod($j_$k) 1Mb 10ms DropTail
```

Is there in general a specific way to group sets of node in a naming convention. What I am thinking is a fat-tree topology so for k=4 we have 4 core switches 4 pod with 2 layers, each having 2 switches, and the lower layer connected to 2 servers/hosts. So I was thinking to have the core in an array and connect them using loops with all the rest nodes where the name would be like something

> pod[0-(k-1)]_layer[0-1]_switch[0-k/2]

The following seems to work but I want to make sure that it's not a fluke

```
set p 0
set l 0
set s 0

set pod(0,0,0) [$ns node]
set pod(0,0,1) [$ns node]

for {set j 0} {$j < 1} {incr j} {
    $ns duplex-link $pod($p,$l,$j) $pod($p,$l,[expr ($j+1)]) 1Gb 10ms DropTail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ns_ at $stime "$node_($src) label \"$label\""

$ns_ at 0.0 "$c($i) label \"corei\""
```

Comment: NS2 is an event driven simulation tools based on timing.
Once a simulation is started, the status of a node is reset.
So the label should be reassigned after the simulation is started.

Comment: To format code, either indent it by 4 spaces or select a codeblock and click `{}` button; equivalently, press Ctrl-K. (I formatted this codeblock.)